# need help in api result for compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-monitoring

I am new to google apis and I am collecting monitoring metric information through apis

for cpu utilization i am using this api

```
https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/my-project/timeSeries?pageSize=500&interval.startTime=2020-07-13T17:30:06Z&aggregation.alignmentPeriod=3600s&aggregation.perSeriesAligner=align_SUM&filter=metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization" AND metric.labels.instance_name="my-instancename"&pageToken=&interval.endTime=2020-07-14T17:30:06Z&alt=json&aggregation.groupByFields=metric.labels.key
```

I have given the aligner as align_sum and the metric type

```
compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization
```

and aggregate alignment period is 3600s

and utilization is coming in the form of doublevalue

Here is the result it starts from 2020-07-14T16:30:06Z and ends with 2020-07-13T18:30:06Z

```
{
  "timeSeries": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "labels": {
          "instance_name": "my-instancename"
        },
        "type": "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"
      },
      "resource": {
        "type": "gce_instance",
        "labels": {
          "project_id": "my-project",
          "zone": "us-central1-a",
          "instance_id": "734343433"
        }
      },
      "metricKind": "GAUGE",
      "valueType": "DOUBLE",
      "points": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T16:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T16:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 7.6894335467752173
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T15:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T15:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 10.759589985275971
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T14:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T14:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 12.316655567177508
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T13:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T13:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 12.728700633146035
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T12:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T12:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 12.727092186095067
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T11:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T11:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 12.653159778132306
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T10:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T10:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 12.760028718919907
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T09:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T09:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.468505218942028
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T08:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T08:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.517169812102356
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T07:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T07:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.608358825287452
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T06:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T06:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.53897596539931
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T05:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T05:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.546214478312317
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T04:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T04:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.438030445192032
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T03:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T03:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.540240797295567
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T02:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T02:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.445462736608853
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T01:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T01:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.628532548211796
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T00:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T00:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.595787295526025
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-13T23:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-13T23:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.612668592590264
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-13T22:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-13T22:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.508062526394571
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-13T21:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-13T21:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.557865914903669
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-13T20:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-13T20:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.615398551388523
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-13T19:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-13T19:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.59927301647136
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-13T18:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-13T18:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 13.576294740418575
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "unit": "10^2.%"
}
```

Due to me infamiliar with this apis i am not able to interpret the results properly

ex:  what does this result below mean for this time period? I had given aggreagate of 3600s so does this mean for every 1 hour i.e. 2020-07-14T01:30:06Z to 2020-07-14T012:30:06Z the cpu has utilized this much for that period or only for this point of instance 2020-07-14T01:30:06Z that much has been utilized. Since the starttime and endtime is coming as same for this gauge metric i need understanding on this. I have given ALIGN_SUM so is the value displayed the summation of 1 hour?

```
"interval": {
                    "startTime": "2020-07-14T01:30:06Z",
                    "endTime": "2020-07-14T01:30:06Z"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "doubleValue": 13.628532548211796
                  }
```

Also the unit for this utilzation is given as   `"unit": "10^2.%".` Should i convert this utilization value to percentage by diving (13.62/100) further to represent in charts as I need to make report out of this?
Kindly help me as i am not much familiar with monitoring apis in google. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

In terms of reading and collecting monitoring metric information through Google APIs, I would suggest referencing [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics) documentation on reading metric data. This document explains how to read metric data, also called time-series data, using the timeSeries.list method in the Monitoring API.

Additionally, with the documentation above, you will also [find](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#timeseries-list-data) a example of getting time series data which should explain in details on how these logs can be broken down and how to utilize to your advantage.

Moreover, in terms of the **unit** for this utilization is given as `"unit": "10^2.%"`, it is based on our documentation on Method: **[projects.timeSeries.list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list)**. As we can see, the **unit** holds all timeSeries point values that are reported within the project. The unit follows the UCUM format for units as seen in https://unitsofmeasure.org/ucum.html. Furthermore, if different timeSeries have different units (for example, because they come from different metric types, or a unit is absent), then unit will be "{not_a_unit}".